# How to implement one-to-many relationship Using JdbcTemplate in spring 2.0 for insert query with simple example

Tags: mysql, spring, one-to-many, sql-insert, jdbctemplate

Please provide code for implementing one-to-many relationship using JdbcTemplate class in Spring 2.0 for inserting records in parent and child tables of sql with simple example like student and course tables. I am beginner to spring. Please provide code. Thank you.